# Post is not working in MVC

Tags: .net

```
   **View:**
   @model BusinessLayer.Family
   @{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm("FamilyDetails", "Family", FormMethod.Post))
    {
     <input id="btn_submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }

    **controller:**
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FamilyDetails()
    {
        Family mymodel = new Family();
        return View(mymodel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string FamilyDetails()
    {
        return "Family";
    }
```

Without using Layout Post is Working.When i am using Layout,Get is firing instead of post.Please Help me.thank you

Comment: Thanks.it's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please Specify Form Method in Begin form Area at least, because by default it calls Post Method.When you are using Layout Action is Partially rendered in the body of Layout so it hits the get area of Action. But when you are using without layout it is having a direct URL of an action and by default it is hitting to Post area of an action.

Comment: Thanks! I did exactly what you suggested.But it is not working.

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("login","Account",FormMethod.Post))
     {

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("submit", "controllername",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
  <input id="btn_submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: @Revathi change the httppost method return type to actionresult and try

Comment: tried this.but not working.i got the answer.i used form tag in layout file.by removing form tag in layout file it is working.but i have a doubt. can't we use nested form.

Comment: @Revathi I think Nested forms aren't permitted in HTML. but There can be several forms in a single document, but the FORM element can't be nested.